# I can't save user identity in yii2

Tags: php, api, yii2

I created a module in *yii2* under *api/modules/v1* folder, the problem is when I request:

```
Yii::$app->user->login($user, 3600);
```

The identity got saved temporary until I refresh the page or I request another url, When I reviewed the log file, I found this : 
**User '1' logged in from ::1. Session not enabled.**
Also I tried to add :

```
'enableAutoLogin' => true,
'enableSession' => true,
```

user component configuration :

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_APIUser', // unique for backend
            'path' => '/api/web/v1'  // correct path for the backend app.
        ]
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => '_apiSessionId', // unique for frontend
        'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime', // a temporary folder on frontend
    ],
```

But the same problem occurred.

Comment: show `user` component configuration.

Comment: @InsaneSkull i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you model common\models\User implements "login" method? If so, login with this code

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->login($user, 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are configuring 'common\config\main' as you have indicated frontend and backend session details in the same config.

Leave the common\config\main blank and you have to configure your backend\config\main and frontend\config\main separately. Your login code should work.